# Swiperjs действия при resize

Tags: javascript, swiper

Проблема что мы при resize на 768 и меньше отключаем карусель, но при возврате на больший экран карусель уже не работает. Как я понимаю проблема кроется в этой функции mySwiper.update();

```js
сonst slider = document.querySelector('.reviews__body');
let mySwiper = new Swiper(slider, {
    observer: true,
    observeParents: true,
    slidesPerView: 2,
    spaceBetween: 0,
    speed: 800,
    preloadImages: false,
    lazy: {
        loadPrevNext: true,
    },
    pagination: {
        el: '.reviews-slider__dotts',
        clickable: true,
    },
    breakpoints: {
        320: false,
        768: {
            slidesPerView: 1.5,
            spaceBetween: 20,
        },
        992: {
            slidesPerView: 2,
            spaceBetween: 0,
        },
    },
    init: false
});

function mobileSlider() {
    slider.dataset.mobile == 'false';
    slider.dataset.destroy == 'false';

    if (window.innerWidth >= 767 && slider.dataset.mobile != 'true') {
        if(slider.dataset.destroy != 'true'){
            console.log('init');
            mySwiper.init();
        }else{
            console.log('update');
            mySwiper.update();
        }
        slider.dataset.mobile = 'false';
    }

    if (window.innerWidth <= 768) {
        slider.dataset.mobile = 'true';
        if (slider.classList.contains('swiper-initialized')) {
            console.log('destroy');
            mySwiper.destroy(true, true);
            slider.dataset.destroy = 'true';
        }
    }else{
        slider.dataset.mobile = 'false';
    }
}

mobileSlider();

window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
    mobileSlider();
});
```

```html
<section class="reviews">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="reviews__title main-title">reviews about us</div>
    <div class="reviews__body swiper">
      <div class="reviews-slider swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <div class="reviews-slider__slide">
            <div class="reviews-slider__item">
              <svg>
                <use xlink:href="./img/sprite.svg#bg"></use>
              </svg>
              <div class="reviews-slider__row">
                <div class="reviews-slider__user">
                  <div class="reviews-slider__image">
                    <img class="swiper-lazy" data-src="img/slider-rewiws/01.jpg" alt="">
                  </div>
                  <div class="reviews-slider__info">
                    <div class="reviews-slider__name">Victoria</div>
                    <div class="reviews-slider__work">CEO</div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="reviews-slider__content">
                  <div class="reviews-slider__text">“We stopped on this company, because of their CEO’s
                    excellent business skills, communication, professional ethics. I would recommend Alex
                    without hesitation to any Small Business who need help in promoting on the Internet.”
                  </div>
                  <div class="reviews-slider__icon">
                    <img class="swiper-lazy" data-src="img/slider-rewiws/02.png" alt="">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <div class="reviews-slider__slide">
            <div class="reviews-slider__item">
              <svg>
                <use xlink:href="./img/sprite.svg#bg"></use>
              </svg>
              <div class="reviews-slider__row">
                <div class="reviews-slider__user">
                  <div class="reviews-slider__image">
                    <img class="swiper-lazy" data-src="img/slider-rewiws/04.jpg" alt="">
                  </div>
                  <div class="reviews-slider__info">
                    <div class="reviews-slider__name">Rosen</div>
                    <div class="reviews-slider__work">Founder</div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="reviews-slider__content">
                  <div class="reviews-slider__text">“Alex gave me the best possible plans and tactics on how to
                    develop the product message to attract the right customers. I look for the opportunity to
                    collaborate with him in the near future.” asd saddasd dasd
                  </div>
                  <div class="reviews-slider__icon">
                    <img class="swiper-lazy" data-src="img/slider-rewiws/03.png" alt="">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <div class="reviews-slider__slide">
            <div class="reviews-slider__item">
              <svg>
                <use xlink:href="./img/sprite.svg#bg"></use>
              </svg>
              <div class="reviews-slider__row">
                <div class="reviews-slider__user">
                  <div class="reviews-slider__image">
                    <img class="swiper-lazy" data-src="img/slider-rewiws/05.jpg" alt="">
                  </div>
                  <div class="reviews-slider__info">
                    <div class="reviews-slider__name">Andrew</div>
                    <div class="reviews-slider__work">CEO in Lasers Only</div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="reviews-slider__content">
                  <div class="reviews-slider__text">“We stopped on this company, because of their CEO’s
                    excellent business skills, communication, professional ethics. I would recommend Alex
                    without hesitation to any Small Business who need help in promoting on the Internet.”
                  </div>
                  <div class="reviews-slider__icon">
                    <img class="swiper-lazy" data-src="img/slider-rewiws/03.png" alt="">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="reviews-slider__dotts dotts dotts_no-arrow"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Проблема кроется в инициализации свайпера. Я считаю, что нужно заново инициализировать новый swiper

Comment: @WalkMess ну тут не весь мусор при destroy уходит с него ) при init выходит ошибка Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'wrapperClass') Хотя я глянул класс этот в html висит.